# build script: how to implement a "skip previously completed step"

Tags: bash, msys, mingw

I'm trying to create a build script for GCC (which works, for now), but I would like to be able to skip rebuilding all the prereq libraries when I'm only updating GCC/binutils for example. I thought of making the script create a file in the main build directory containing all the steps to skip. How would I do that (something with the `cat` command and find to see if a step is in the file?). This would allow me, albeit manually, to enable a rebuild of certain parts when needed.

UPDATE: The answers posted seem to assume that I need a makefile, while I find that very troublesome and don't want it; the build procedure consists of many cd, configure, make, make install steps that I simply don't want in a makefile. The script is near-finished, this is the last step I need for it...

UPDATE2: as I said in the comment below, I'm on windows, using MSYS bash as shell.

Thanks!

PS: this "skipping completed steps" needs to be performed each time the script is run.

Comment: Why are you building gcc & co. Wouldn't it be better to use it from system repositories?

Comment: I live on Windows x64, which a) doesn't have system repositories, and b) I'm experimenting and would like to build a x64 MinGW-w64 compiler with GCC 4.6

Comment: Despite your saying that you *don't* want to use Make, it seems that what you're doing is exactly what Make is built for --- it's a dependency resolution system ... which it looks like you're wanting to build yourself.

Comment: @Eric, no... I'm trying to create a BASH shell script, which runs a given set of commands, like TDM has for his GCC builds, and many others also use. That's what I want a variation of, not a makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it looks like you're not really asking a question around build frameworks, but rather a specific question about how to determine if a certain line exists in a text file?

If you want to find out if the string `foo` exists in a file, then:

```
if grep -q foo thefile; then
   # it's there
else
   # otherwise
fi
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Great, that's already half of it. I did mention Bash in my questionnot anything CMake/Make/Scons or something like that... Would an `echo "foo\n" > thefile` do the job for creating the file? Will it append "foo" to the file, or create a new one and overwrite the previous? Thanks

Comment: Never mind: I have what I wanted: `echo "foo" >> test` with your magic should do the trick!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need an introduction to `make`, produced by our friends over at GNU, I believe.

Make can look at a bunch of intermediate files and determine which ones need to be recompiled. And based on which one(s) of those, also figure out which ones need their supporting files rebuilt, thus recursing.

You will need to set it up in advance by creating a Makefile, but this is something which it sounds like you are willing to do.

For more information, I would check out this URL: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/. Actually, bullet point number 2 sounds like it does a better job of describing it than anything I could do.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/documentation.html). For what you've described, it's probably overkill and `make` would be a better fit, but if you start getting into the [`autotools`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) stuff, it could make your life a lot easier.

Comment: CMake and autotools don't fit the same niche... autotools will make the program compile (when used correctly) on any platform with `sh`, wherease CMake will require CMake on all the platforms, which is fine if your not going to want full portability. I would list CMake and autotools as different options for similar tasks.